# Javascript: What is the difference between usage of . and : operators for specifying a variable in a function or object?

Tags: javascript, function, static-members

For using a static variable in javascript functions I found out two ways, using . and : operator.
 When using . operator we have to specify variable with "f.variable" and when using : we have to use "this.variable". what is the difference between the usage of these two operators.

```
function f(){
  f.a += 1;
  this.b += 1;
  console.log("f.a: ", f.a);
  console.log("this.b: ", this.b);
}
f.a = 0;
f:b = 0;
```

also we cannot use : when using that variable outside its function like:

```
function g(){
  f:b = 0; //this works fine.
  var c = f:b; //raises error invalid label.
  console.log(f:b);//but this raises an error missing ')'.
}
```

Same is the case when we use var to create objects.

```
var obj = {
 a: 2,
 b: 3
}
//accessing a and b is done using obj.a & obj.b
//but here
obj:a = 4;
console.log(f.a); // this gives 2
//and similarly using obj:a as rhs value gives error.
```

How are these two operators used actually.

EDIT:
What is the difference between these two types of variables created.

Comment: you should not use `f:b = 0;` notation. The syntax is correct but the meaning is not. Use `var b = 0;` for variable and `var o = { b:0 };` for object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
f:b = 0;
```

is interpreted as a [*label*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), "f", before an expression statement, `b = 0;`.  The ":" is used in [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2C_Variables%2C_and_Literals#Object_literals) syntax to separate a property name expression from its value expression. Otherwise, it is not used for referring to properties of objects.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I think that labels are only accessible within the scope they are defined; that is an assumption I am making since I rarely, if ever really, use labels in my code. If I were a better person I would create a test for this to find out for sure.

Comment: I am curious. Can someone tell me why 'console.log(f:b)' generates raises an error missing *')'*?

Comment: @DanielK. it's because the parser guesses that you meant to type `console.log() f:b ...` or something like that. In other words, the "f:" is meaningless in that context, so it assumes you forgot to finish the previous expression before starting a new statement.

Comment: but what type of variable it creates for that function and how is it different from `f.b = 0;`

Comment: Inside the function f variable defined using `f.b = 0;` is accessed as `f.b;` only but variable defined as `f:b = 0;` is accessed inside function f as `this.b` what is the difference between these two variables in terms of scope or storage etc.

Comment: @rajan just never use ":" unless you're writing an object literal.  It **never** makes sense outside of that context.